# How to convert timestamp in label to number of seconds since "now" in MetricsQL?

Tags: victoriametrics, metricsql

The Kubernetes `kubernetes_build_info` metric contains label `build_date`.

Example:

```
kubernetes_build_info{build_date="2023-10-18T11:33:23Z",compiler="gc",git_commit="07a61d861519c45ef5c89bc22dda289328f29343",git_tree_state="clean",git_version="v1.27.7",go_version="go1.20.10",major="1",minor="27",platform="linux/amd64"} 1
```

How to convert the `build_date` label to number of seconds since "now" using MetricsQL?